# MYSQL > count number of records added at the same time

Tags: mysql, count

Firstly, i have already searched the website and couldn't find anything to achieve the results i require.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
id  calldate            disposition     user_id
1   12/16/2012 21:34    ANSWERED        21
2   12/16/2012 21:34    ANSWERED        21
3   12/16/2012 21:59    ANSWERED        21
4   12/16/2012 22:11    ANSWERED        21
5   12/16/2012 22:11    FAILED          21
```

now i want to count the numbers of rows that were inserted on the same time (mathing the time and status of the row).

So for the above records the results would be something like:

```
calldate            count
12/16/2012 21:34    2
12/16/2012 21:59    1
```

and here is what i have achieved so far but still can't get the desired results.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total, 
    DATE(calldate) AS date, 
    HOUR(calldate) AS hour, 
    calldate
FROM calls 
WHERE disposition='ANSWERED'
GROUP BY date, hour HAVING total > 1 ORDER BY calldate ASC
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: "but still can't get the desired results" --- what results do you have? How exactly they don't match the desired results? In your desired results you're grouping by date and time including minutes, whereas in your attempt you're grouping only by a date and an hour, without minutes. Haven't you noticed it?

Comment: the results i am getting are calculating all rows of that day, instead of breaking them into calldate. yeah i just noticed let me give minutes a try.

Comment: Hey @zerkms thanks for the tip, this was the case, i was missing the minutes which was causing difference in results. thank you

P.S: Kindly post your tip below so i may accept this as an answer.

Comment: it doesn't worth it :-) Just check Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT calldate, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM calls 
WHERE disposition = 'ANSWERED'
GROUP BY calldate
HAVING total > 1
ORDER BY calldate ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff the query you gave was also helpfull however my issue was resolved by adding the minutes to group by clause.